# How to add a dot and convert a number each two number

Tags: r

I have this number in R : C0290614 in hexadecimal.

If the input is in hexadecimal and the output is asked in hexadecimal, the output has to be :
C0.29.06.14 (Just putting a dot each 2 numbers).

If the input is in hexadecimal and the output is asked in decimal, the output has to be :
192.41.6.20 (Convert in decimal two by two then put a dot at each number converted)

In resume :

Input :
C0290614 16

**Output :
C0.29.06.14**

Input :
C0290614 10

**Output :
192.41.6.20**

Help me get the output please

To begin :

```
Convert <- function(addr, base) {
    if (base == 16) {
a <- as.integer(as.hexmode("C0"))
b <- as.integer(as.hexmode("29"))
c <- as.integer(as.hexmode("06"))
d <- as.integer(as.hexmode("14"))
cat(a, b , c, d)
        

    } else if (base == 10) {

    }


    return(paste0(addr, "-", base))
}

Convert(C0290614, 16)
```

Comment: To start Convert <- function(addr, base) {
 if (base == 16) {
  

 } else if (base == 10) {

 }


    return(paste0(addr, "-", base))
}

Convert(C0290614, 16)

Comment: Put the code you tried in your post please rather than in a comment.

Comment: What's the logic between `C0290614 10` and `192.41.6.20`?

Comment: It's converted from hexadecimal to decimal

Comment: C0 29 06 14 is converted to 192 41 6 20

Comment: It's first separated two by two then converted

Comment: And the 10 is to precise that I have to convert it in decimal

Comment: How do you determine if a different number is in hexadecimal or decimal? Not all hexidecimal numbers have letters in them.

Comment: I have only hexadecimal number to begin

Comment: Maybe providing `5` to `10` sample values of hexadecimals and decimals from your data using `dput()` will also help with your question.

Comment: In your question, you say you can have either hex or decimal numbers as input

Comment: Yes it's a mistake I modified it

Comment: @Ed_Gravy
Just how can I separate a number two by two first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting *hex* to *numeric*

```
d <- "C0290614"

paste(as.numeric(as.hexmode(substring(
  d, seq(1, nchar(d), 2), seq(2, nchar(d), 2)))), collapse=".")
[1] "192.41.6.20"
```

Comment: Let me try this, thanks a lot dude !

Comment: Haha I got 100% thanks